One way Elasticsearch synonyms
I'm currently facing the same issue with the synonym analyzer.
Here is the behavior I'd like to achieve:

Query for "cable" will return the results for "cable" and "cordon"
Query for "cordon" will return only the results for "cordon".

For the moment, the queries below return all the results with "cable" and "cordon"
Query #1 with "cable":
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "simple_query_string": {
                                    "query": "cable",
                                    "analyzer": "french",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "label"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}

Query #2 with "cordon"
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "simple_query_string": {
                                    "query": "cordon",
                                    "analyzer": "french",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "label"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}

The index settings:
{
    "lifecycle": {
        "name": "pdb-policy"
    },
    "routing": {
        "allocation": {
            "include": {
                "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
        }
    },
    "mapping": {
        "total_fields": {
            "limit": "10000"
        }
    },
    "number_of_shards": "1",
    "provided_name": "products2",
    "creation_date": "1719059028223",
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "alphanumeric": {
                "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z0-9]",
                "type": "pattern_replace",
                "replacement": ""
            },
            "french_stop": {
                "type": "stop",
                "stopwords": "_french_"
            },
            "limit1term": {
                "type": "limit",
                "max_token_count": "1"
            },
            "synonym_monodirectional": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms_path": "synonyms\/words.txt",
                "expand": "false"
            },
            "french_elision": {
                "type": "elision",
                "articles": [
                    "l",
                    "m",
                    "t",
                    "qu",
                    "n",
                    "s",
                    "j",
                    "d",
                    "c",
                    "jusqu",
                    "quoiqu",
                    "lorsqu",
                    "puisqu"
                ]
            },
            "limit3term": {
                "type": "limit",
                "max_token_count": "3"
            },
            "french_stemmer": {
                "name": "french",
                "type": "stemmer"
            }
        },
        "normalizer": {
            "transliterator": {
                "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "space_addition": {
                "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "french_elision",
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym_monodirectional",
                    "french_stop"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "prefix1term": {
                "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "french_elision",
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym_monodirectional",
                    "french_stop",
                    "limit1term"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "space_removal": {
                "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "french_elision",
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym_monodirectional",
                    "french_stop"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "french": {
                "filter": [
                    "synonym_monodirectional"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "prefix3term": {
                "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "french_elision",
                    "lowercase",
                    "synonym_monodirectional",
                    "french_stop",
                    "limit3term"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "transliterator": {
                "filter": [
                    "asciifolding",
                    "lowercase"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    },
    "priority": "100",
    "number_of_replicas": "0",
    "uuid": "ePDgepPcTm-NLcaePn6f3Q",
    "version": {
        "created": "7170999"
    }
}

The synonyms file:
cable => cordon

The analyzers seem to be correct too:
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "cordon",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "cordon",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "SYNONYM",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}

Do you have any idea?
Thank you for your help.

There are two issues here. The first issues is that your "french" analyzer is basically just a standard tokenizer with synonyms. It will not even lowercase tokens. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78634671/783043 for detailed discussion.
The second issue is that during search we need to expand cable into both cable and cardon instead of just cordon. There are several ways to do it depending on the types of synonyms, but the simplest way would probably just adding the original token to the mapping. If we combine both solutions for both issues together we will get something like this:
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "label": {
        "type": "text", 
        "analyzer": "french_index",
        "search_analyzer": "french_search"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "french_elision": {
          "type":         "elision",
          "articles_case": true,
          "articles": [
              "l", "m", "t", "qu", "n", "s",
              "j", "d", "c", "jusqu", "quoiqu",
              "lorsqu", "puisqu"
            ]
        },
        "french_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_french_" 
        },
        "french_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "light_french"
        },
        "synonym_monodirectional": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": ["cable => cable,cordon"],
          "expand": "true"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "french_search": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "french_elision",
            "lowercase",
            "french_stop",
            "synonym_monodirectional",
            "french_stemmer"
          ]
        },
        "french_index": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "french_elision",
            "lowercase",
            "french_stop",
            "french_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh=true
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{ "label": "This is a cable."}
{ "index": { "_id": "2" } }
{ "label": "C'est un cordon."}

POST test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "cable",
            "fields": [
                "label"
            ]
        }
    }
}

POST test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "cordon",
            "fields": [
                "label"
            ]
        }
    }
}


I've followed the instructions but I have the same issue with this query:
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"query":{"simple_query_string":{"query":"cable","analyzer":"french","fields":["label"]}}}'

You didn't follow the example correctly. The query in the instructions doesn't have any analyzers in the query. If you want to use an analyzer it should be french_search and not french in my example.

It doesn't work without the analyzer too.

Which version of elasticsearch are you using? I just re-tested it on 8.13.4, it works and this is the output that I get: https://gist.github.com/imotov/8a848a34877df3527b75b48840d017ad as you can see the first search gives me both records and the second search gives me only one. What doesn't work for you?
